# rsyslog truncate message also with $MaxMessageSize

Tags: logging, rsyslog

I have an official alpine container with rsyslog installed, my `/etc/rsyslog.conf` is:

```
$MaxMessageSize 64k
$ModLoad imuxsock # provides support for local system logging
$ModLoad imklog   # provides kernel logging support
$KLogPermitNonKernelFacility on
$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat
$FileOwner root
$FileGroup adm
$FileCreateMode 0640
$DirCreateMode 0755
$Umask 0022

*.*;auth,authpriv.none          -/var/log/syslog
```

I run rsyslog with `rsyslogd -f /etc/rsyslog.conf`, it seems that `$MaxMessageSize` is 1k instead than 64k
Where am I wrong?

**UPDATE**

I have try within ubuntu container and work perfectly, it seems that alpine is the problem, into ubuntu rsyslog is version 7.4.4, into alpine 8.18.0

**UPDATE 2**

I have tried also with syslog-ng and have same result, max size 1k, maybe is a limit of alpine docker container?

Comment: You will have to set the MaxMessageSize parameter on both the client(sender) as well as the server(receiver). This is the mistake which i was making when i faced a similar issue. Worked for me when i set it on the client as well.

Comment: No client exists, into /var/log/syslog i put logs of php application, then i get with filebeat/logstash for elk logging. I use the official php-fpm-alpine container

Answer (score 3):

I stumbled on the same problem yesterday and after some digging, I found the reason.

I'll make it short : the `libc` lib used on alpine is the `musl libc` (https://www.musl-libc.org/). If you check their implementation of the `syslog` function (https://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/misc/syslog.c#n87), you can see that the length of the variable `buf` that represent the message is hardcoded to 1024.

One solution is to connect and send the message (implementing the syslog RFC) to the `/dev/log` socket yourself. It works well.

Another one might be to use `glibc` on alpine lib but I do not know if it's actually possible.